# How to avoid malformed URI sequence error?

Tags: perl, escaping, malformed

I'm working with perl. I have data saved on database as  `Â â€œ`

and I want to escape those characters to avoid having malformed URI sequence error on the client side. This error seems to happen on fire fox only. The fix I found while googling is not to use `decodeURI` , yet I need this for other characters to be displayed correctly.

Any help? `uri_escape` does not seem enough on the server side.

Thanks in advance.

---

Detalils:
In perl I'm doing the following:

```
print "<div style='display:none;' id='summary_".$note_count."_note'>".uri_escape($summary)."</div>";
```

and on the java script side I want to read from this div and place it on another place as this:

```
getObj('summary_div').innerHTML= unescape(decodeURI(note_obj.innerHTML));
```

where the note_obj is the hidden div that saved the summary on perl.
When I remove decodeURI the problem is solved, I don't get malformed URI sequence error on java script. Yet I need to use decodeURI for other characters.

This issue seems to be reproduced on firefox and IE7.

Comment: Why does uri_escape not seem to be enough? Show what you tried. :)

Comment: I added details about the issue.

Comment: Do you mean your database contains incorrect UTF-8?  Or do you mean your database contains UTF-8 which is correct but it looks like that when you look at it with a Latin-1 tool?  Can you show the actual bytes you have there, especially if you are not sure what this means?

Comment: @tripleee, well the issue is that I'm not reading the whole string, which makes a problem in parsing data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the CGI module, and perform

```
$uri = CGI::escape($uri);
```

maybe it depends of the context your try to escape the uri.
This worked fine for me in CGI context.

After you added details, i can suggest :

```
<div style='display:none;' id='summary_".$note_count."_note'>".CGI::escape($summary)."</div>";
```

Comment: i admit that i don't really understand your question : do you need to encode or decode the uri ?

Answer (score 0):

URL escaping won't help you here -- that's for escaping URLs, not escaping text in HTML.  What you really want is to encode the string when you output it.  See the [Encode.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode) built-in library.  Make sure that you get your charset statements right in the HTTP headers: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" or something like that.

If you're unlucky, you may also have to decode the string as it comes out of the database.  That depends on the database driver and the encoding...